# Несанкционированный вход в интернет

Tags: безопасность, администрирование, реестр, firewall, cisco

Столкнулся с проблемой Несанкционированного доступа в интернет.
Есть локальная сеть,выходит через cisco во внешний мир,но не в интернет,а на другие локальные внутренние сети.
Пришло письмо что был выход в интернет,причем установленный, не попытка зайти.

То есть это могли через мобильный интернет, смартфон подключить через usb-модем.
Как найти следы входа?
Пробовал посмотреть изменение ип, думал если через модем выходил во внешний мир,то надо была по dhcp получить ip адрес или этого не надо?
Искал данные в реестре.

Так же смотрел последние запущенные программы,думал может ломится программа в интернет,в том же реестре,папке Windows/Preferth/. Сетевой мониторинг.

Смотрел подключение в реестре usb, но там ничего подозрительного,флешшки 16,32 гб)

Смотрел ipconfig /displaydns - думал следы останутся днс кеша.

Думал в журнале фаервола есть следы,но там журнал не ввелся.
Операционная система Win 7/10
Подскажите, бо я там понял тут надо больше знаний, как еще можно который определить несанкционированый вход в интернет,который был задним числом.

Comment: А откуда у пользователей права на установку дров\софта, раз такая защищённая подсеть?

Comment: Софт был изначально перед вводом домен,потом права админа получают через laps, ограниченные. Но на установку там прав нет, отдельное заявление писать на debug.